# Java play complex data binding with JSON

Tags: java, angularjs, playframework, playframework-2.0

I'm having an issue using the @OneToMany bindings and the bindFromRequest method from Java Play. Currently I have a Client model that has many FinancialAsset models

```
@Entity
public class Client extends Model {

...
@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "client")
public List<FinancialAsset> assetList;
...
}
```

Here is the gist of my FinancialAsset model

```
@Entity
public class FinancialAsset extends Model {

@Id
public long id;

@ManyToOne(optional = false)
@JoinColumn(name="client", referencedColumnName = "id")
public Client client;

public enum AssetType {
    K401, ANNUITY, CASH, CD, GOLD, IRA, PARTNERSHIP, RENTAL_PROP, RETIREMENT_ACCT
}

public float totalValue;
public AssetType realAssetType;

public String financialInstitute;

public String description;

public void setRealAssetType (String assetTypeString) {
    this.realAssetType = AssetType.valueOf(assetTypeString);
}

public static List<AssetType> getAllAssetTypes() {
    List<AssetType> all = new ArrayList<AssetType>(Arrays.asList(AssetType.values()));
    return all;
}

public static Finder<Long,FinancialAsset> find = new Finder(Long.class, FinancialAsset.class);

public static List<FinancialAsset> allForClient(Client client) {
    return find.where().eq("clientId", client.id).findList();
}
}
```

When my front end client (Angular.js) calls my method for updating a client with the following data:

```
{
    id: 1234,
    assetList: Array[1]
        assetType: "ANNUITY",
        totalValue: 50000,
        description: "blah",
        financialInstitue: "blahstitute",
    otherClientproperties: "..."
}
```

It tries to bindFromRequest but errors when I do a get() to get the client:

```
@BodyParser.Of(play.mvc.BodyParser.Json.class)
public static Result editClientJSON() {
    Logger.debug("Reached editClientJSON");
    Form<Client> clientForm = Form.form(Client.class);
    //Error is here on the get
    Client client = clientForm.bindFromRequest().get();

    client.update();
    Logger.debug("Client updated: " + client.name);
    response().setHeader(LOCATION, routes.ClientCtrl.getClientJSON(client.id).url());

    return ok();
}
```

Error output:

```
play.api.Application$$anon$1: Execution exception[[IllegalStateException: No value]]
at play.api.Application$class.handleError(Application.scala:289) ~[play_2.10.jar:2.1.1]
at play.api.DefaultApplication.handleError(Application.scala:383) [play_2.10.jar:2.1.1]
at play.core.server.netty.PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler$$anon$2$$anonfun$handle$1.apply(PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler.scala:144) [play_2.10.jar:2.1.1]
at play.core.server.netty.PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler$$anon$2$$anonfun$handle$1.apply(PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler.scala:140) [play_2.10.jar:2.1.1]
at play.api.libs.concurrent.PlayPromise$$anonfun$extend1$1.apply(Promise.scala:113) [play_2.10.jar:2.1.1]
at play.api.libs.concurrent.PlayPromise$$anonfun$extend1$1.apply(Promise.scala:113) [play_2.10.jar:2.1.1]
java.lang.IllegalStateException: No value
at play.libs.F$None.get(F.java:540) ~[play_2.10.jar:2.1.1]
at play.data.Form.get(Form.java:525) ~[play-java_2.10.jar:2.1.1]
at controllers.ClientCtrl.editClientJSON(ClientCtrl.java:60) ~[na:na]
at Routes$$anonfun$routes$1$$anonfun$applyOrElse$14$$anonfun$apply$14.apply(routes_routing.scala:225) ~[na:na]
at Routes$$anonfun$routes$1$$anonfun$applyOrElse$14$$anonfun$apply$14.apply(routes_routing.scala:225) ~[na:na]
at play.core.Router$HandlerInvoker$$anon$6$$anon$2.invocation(Router.scala:164) ~[play_2.10.jar:2.1.1]
```

My thought is that its having trouble binding the assetList to FinancialAsset models. I'm not sure how to debug this or to figure out what its looking for.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

It seems like a validation problem. You should check for form errors before getting the underlying object from the form since the binding might fail and there might be no underlying object to acquire. Try out the following code to detect and display any form errors:

```
@BodyParser.Of(play.mvc.BodyParser.Json.class)
public static Result editClientJSON() {
    Logger.debug("Reached editClientJSON");
    Form<Client> clientForm = Form.form(Client.class).bindFromRequest();

    if(clientForm.hasErrors()) {//check out for form errors
        for (String errorKey : clientForm.errors().keySet()) {
            for (ValidationError error : clientForm.errors().get(errorKey)) {
                Logger.error(error.key() + " = " + error.message());                 
            }
        }
        return badRequest();
    }

    //There is no error on the form so it is now safe to get the Client
    Client client = clientForm.get();
    client.update();
    Logger.debug("Client updated: " + client.name);
    response().setHeader(LOCATION, routes.ClientCtrl.getClientJSON(client.id).url());

    return ok();
}
```

Comment: Thank you for you help. Unfortunately the form doesn't appear to have any errors. Debugging allowed me to step all the way to clientForm.get() where it continued to throw the same error. While debugging I did notice that it seems to think the form has no data. The request appears to have the data under a json section but under urlFormEncoded or xml it says "None". "None" is also what the form thinks it has after bindFromRequest. I'm wondering if maybe this is an annotation issue or a json issue.

Comment: Digging deeper in the debug it seems like neither bind nor bindFromRequest are getting called. If I evaluate request().body().asJson() I get the proper data sent over in the PUT. However for some reason it doesn't put that data in the clientForm.

Answer (score 0):

This behavior appears to be a bug with the version of play I was using, Play 2.1.1. I upgraded to 2.3 and the issue was resolved. Very frustrating.